# One domain name - two servers? Is It Possible?

Tags: domains, web-development, server, webserver, dns-servers

I want to use one domain name on 2 servers at a time.If one server is not working then my visitors can see my website without any problem from other server.Can i use one domain name on two different hosting services?

Comment: Absolutely! Check out the round-robin DNS technique or even using DNS for fail-over. This is the simplest way to get this done.

Comment: Round robin is not enough. @Zaheer needs a real failover. At the very least, the dead server somehow needs to be removed from the round robin.

Comment: @DamnTerminal I realize that round-robin is primarily used for load-balancing, but it is also used for fail-over in that it can dynamically remove any DNS entry that is in failure. We used several techniques in a global telecom that may or may not have some relationship with Dr. Who and the first method we used was DNS (internal) amongst several others such as clustering, proxies, and so on. It can be done, though I am not sure how to implement it for the OP without thinking about it first.